# The program 'gem' can be found in the following packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm, virtualbox

I'm installing Ruby on Rails on Virtual Box/Ubuntu 13.10. Below are the steps

1. ruby -v

   => The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages ... Try: sudo apt-get install
2. source /my account/...

   ==> Ok.
3. \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash

   => I've got a message thanking me for using RVM. In case of problems, I should consult their website or twitter.
4. rvm requirements

   ==> Requirments installation successful.
5. type rvm | head -n 1

   ==> rvm is a function
6. rvm list known

   ==> I get a list of ruby's versions
7. rvm install 2.0.0 -C --enable-shared, --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local

   ==> Install of ruby 2.0.0 complete. Please consider upgrading to ruby 2.1.0 ...
8. rvm list

   ==> rvm rubies
   =* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [i686 ]

   `# => - current`

   `# =* - current && default`

   `#  * - current`
9. rvm use 2.0.0@railstutorial_rails_4_0 --create --default

   ==> ok.
10. rvm gemset list

    ==> gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p353 ...

    (default)

    global

    => railstutorial_rails_4_0
11. gem -v

    => The program 'gem' can be found in the following packages:

    - ruby1.9.1
    - rubygems
      try: sudo apt-get install

Why do I need to install ruby again? I thought I did so in **step 7**. I've gone over and over the same steps but I don't understand why it keeps telling me to install ruby again.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 23):

On your Terminal window go to Edit>Profile Preferences>Title and command, and check the box that says "Run command as a login shell". Restart your Terminal and try ruby -v and gem -v now. The versions should come up. If they don't then try re-installing them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I spent a couple of days trying to figure out what was wrong with my VirtualBox. Does this only happen in Virtual Box installations?

Comment: @andNoob: No: anecdotally, it's just occurred for me in Linux Mint on real hardware.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the rvm ruby is not actually being used. If you run `ruby -v`, what do you get? I suspect it will be the message from the system about ruby being available in a package. Are you sure your $PATH is set correctly?

If you run `/bin/bash --login` and try again what happens?

Comment: I run `ruby -v`, I got the same error message. However, when I run `/bin/bash --login`, then `ruby -v`, I got `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i686-linux]`

Comment: I've noticed that each time I close the command line, I get the same error until I run again `/bin/bash --login`. Is there a way to make it permanent so I don't have to run this command every time I open the command line?

Comment: However you are connecting to your machine you are not getting a login shell. That's the problem.

Comment: Well, then I need to run /bin/bash --login every time I'm in. That's what I have been doing.

Comment: I tried `cd .bash_profile`, but I got a `not a directory` error.

Answer (score 2):

check what `rvm list` returns.

I had multiple ruby versions installed but had not selected the ruby version to use.

I did `rvm use <ruby_version> --default` then `ruby` as well as `gem` command worked.