# The program 'gem' can be found in the following packages Windows Bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-10

I have installed Ruby via RVM on Windows Insider Build(Ubuntu Bash). RVM installed successfully and so did ruby.

I have also installed bundler with "gem install bundler". Updated few gems and stuff. But now it says on `ruby -v`

```
cooldudeabhi@ACERASPIRE:~$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * ruby1.8
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
cooldudeabhi@ACERASPIRE:~$ gem
The program 'gem' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * rubygems
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
cooldudeabhi@ACERASPIRE:~$
```

I suspect its a PATH problem but I am not sure if it really is? If its a PATH problem I don't know what to set in bashrc files please tell that. Thanks

I have found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650849/the-program-gem-can-be-found-in-the-following-packages) on stackoverflow but it doesn't help in case of Windows.

Also `/usr/local/bin` is empty that's strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your profile settings (.bashrc or .bash_profile)

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

answer referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018598/ruby-on-rails-rvm-path-issue)